# How to combine many SQL queries into one?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have two tables relevant to this question.

The first is `Company` which `has_many` `Taps`.  Each Tap has a Date field that states the date when it was created (different than `created_at` for reasons irrelevant here).

I want to plot the frequency of `Taps` for a company over time, grouping by day.  That means for my 30-day graph, I am currently making a separate SQL query for each `Date` in my range to get app taps where `:tapped_time = {some date} and :company_id = {id of the company}`.

How can I get the number of Taps for a Company on each day in a consecutive range without making a separate query for each day?

I am using Ruby on Rails, so I don't need raw SQL I just need some help with my ActiveRecord magic.

Comment: I realized I was being dumb and I could just load all of the Taps in that range and then filter in code.  But if anyone has some ActiveRecord magic that would do this I'd still be very interested.

Comment: It's probably going to be a lot faster to have the database return the counts than to return all the rows and count them in the application. At the SQL level it will be something like `SELECT Date, count(*) FROM Taps WHERE CompanyId = x GROUP BY Date ORDER BY Date`. See Catcall's answer for a suggestion of how to get to that at the ActiveRecord level.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, you'd group by date if you're querying for a single company, by date and company if you're querying for multiple companies at one time.

ActiveRecord has a [group method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group) for that.

Comment: Can I do this if the column is a DateTime and I want to group by just the Date?

Comment: I doubt it. I think you'll have to convert the DateTime to a date before grouping on it. IN Ruby 1.9.2+, the DateTime class has a [to_date() method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-to_date). You'd do essentially the same thing in SQL--cast a value of type DateTime or Timestamp to Date and group on the result.